# Can someone help me solve $z^{3}=-i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$z$ is a complex number. I tried to solve this question by setting $z=a+bi$, but when I calculated $(a+bi)^{3}$, I found that's a little bit complicated to compute, Can someone help me teach me some easier way to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar form of a complex number?

Comment: @levap yes I am, but I still have no idea how to finish this question.

Comment: Have you learned De Moivre's theorem?  How about Euler's identity?

Comment: It might illuminate things to put this question to Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @Doug M Yes, I learnt De Moivre's theorem. But I have no idea about Euler's identity.

Comment: You seem to have a low bar for "too complicated". While polar form is even simpler, I cannot find anything too complicated in $(a+bi)^3$.

Comment: @celtschk Sorry for my bad English, what I just want to express is "Can I find an easier way to solve this question".

Answer (score 2):

$$z^3 = -i=e^{3\pi i/2+2\pi i n} \implies z =e^{\pi i/2+2\pi i n/3}= i e^{2\pi i n/3}$$

where $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

$z^3=-i \leftrightarrow z^3+i=0 \leftrightarrow (z)^3+(-i)^3=0$.

The LHS factors into $(z-i)(z^2+iz-1)=0$.

Now you have $(z-i)=0 \rightarrow z=i$ and $(z^2+iz-1)=0 \rightarrow z=\frac{-i \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

There was no need to give up on the $(a+bi)^3$ approach.  Just follow the algebra:

$$-i=(a+bi)^3=a^3+3a^2bi-3ab^2-b^3i=(a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$$

implies

$$
a^3-3ab^2=0\quad\text{and}\quad
3a^2b-b^3=-1$$

Factoring the first equation as $a(a^2-3b^2)=0$, we have $a=0$ or $a=\pm\sqrt3b$.

If $a=0$, then the second equation is simply $-b^3=-1$, for which $b=1$ is the only solution.

If $a=\pm3b$, the second equation is $9b^3-b^3=-1$, or $8b^3=-1$, for which $b=-1/2$ is the only solution.  We thus get three solutions to $z^3=-i$:

$$z=
\begin{cases}
i\\
{\sqrt3\over2}-{1\over2}\\
-{\sqrt3\over2}-{1\over2}
\end{cases}$$